# Android wear apk work on Samsung Gear s3

Tags: android, wear-os, tizen

I have developed an application for android wear, my question is how can I run it into Samsung Gear s3 (Tizen OS)? I have tested an application 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ugho.tizen.simplayer_pro&hl=en

which intalls on phone and on wear automatically, So i think my android wear application can also run on samsung gear s3.
TIA

Comment: You have tested APK on Tizen device? how...please share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to run android wear apk on Tizen based Gear s3, You have to develop new Tizen app using Tizen studio
[Download here](https://developer.tizen.org/),
Now you will have option to develop using native, web or .net please check documentation.